# how to disable the onKeyDown effect of a Dpad button in android, i m not using Listacivity.?

Tags: android, listview

I Wrote some code in OnKeyUp event handler, but some by default action of OnKeyDown is taking place whenever i m pressing any button, so i want to disable that action. Plz give me some suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

You can then override the onKeyDown() method in your required activity as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    //here goes your code
}
```

Have a look more at:
[OnKeyDown(keyCode,event)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

Comment: Yes, u r correct, i tried that also, but it was not working. I was returning Null for each KeyCode, but default actions was still present there.